# how to Load CKEditor in div?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

how do i load Ckeditor inside `<div>` i tried forcing ckeditor inside `<div>` like this

```
    $("#divID").load("message.php");
```

but that doesn't work, is there anyway to load a php document that contain the ckeditor inside a `<div>`? other php document works fine when i load it inside `div`?

its also the same with `textboxlist-jquery` it doesnt load, but the buttons inside the same document as those 2 works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","file.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}else{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.open("GET","file.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
$("#divid").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
jQuery.get("message.php",function(data){
  jQuery("#divID").html(data).find('textarea').ckeditor();
});
```

Comment: message.php contains whole html file with `textboxlist-jquery` and `ckeditor textarea`. correct me if i'm mistaken but this code will get what's inside message.php and load it inside the div and it will find a existing textarea in my main.php?

Comment: It will load your external page into the current document, then trigger ckeditor to be enabled on any text area that's been inserted into the page. Infact, did you try it?